# What are service worker gateways used for?

Tags: ipfs

I've noticed that you can launch a node in a Service Worker with `js-ipfs`. I'm curious to know what the difference between a service worker implementation and simply importing a bundled javascript library is.

Example of a [service worker gateway](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/service-worker-gateway).

I'm currently just using an imported js library to `add` and `pin` files, and it seems to work fine. Is a node truly running on the user's browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run [js-ipfs](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs) in your web app, it is a full IPFS node running in the browser. You can talk to it using programmatic interface (`ipfs.add`, `ipfs.cat` etc), just like you described, but it is unable to answer to regular HTTP requests because it can't open TCP port to start HTTP server. This usually is not a problem, but if you want to display an image downloaded from IPFS you need to fetch it via `cat` and inline it as [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs).

What running js-ipfs in Service Worker gives you on top of regular programmantic interface, is the ability to provide responses for HTTP requests to `/ipfs/{CID}` paths, just like [regular gateways](https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/) would do.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between the two? Seems like the service worker implementation is basically convenience from having to write your own handling of requests, is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: Correct. In both cases you run the same JS code ([js-ipfs](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs)), so there is no diff at implementation level. 

If you run a single page app, fetch and display a lot of static data, using Service Worker for returning data may bring you benefits of  [HTTP Caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching) support  provided by browser, but that is about it.

Workers bring the biggest benefit when you want to share the same js-ipfs instance and data repository across browser tabs or different Origins, but those are more advanced use cases and YMMV